# Spring boot not set cookie

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, spring-restcontroller

I tried to set the cookie inside the rest controller. The code is given below. However, in the subsequent calls to the API from the Angular app, the httpRequest.getCookies() is null.

```java
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("authToken", jwtToken);
cookie.setMaxAge(30 * 86400); // 30 days
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setSecure(false);
    
response.addCookie(cookie);
    
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ResponseCodes.SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Unless the path url matches the path it won't be added to the request by the browser. So make sure that those things match for subsequent requests. Depending on your framework you might even need to add it manually to subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum . Since I set the cookie path like this  'cookie.setPath("/")', it should be available to all the paths in the application right. Moreover, for the exact same path also, the getCookieis() returns null.

Comment: Which means something is off. The path maybe correct but that doesn't mean the host and port are set correctly. And depending on your clientside library you might need to add the cookies manually to the request. Assume it is added automatically something simply doesn't match either the, path, host , port etc. of your cookie being send back to the client.

Comment: My clientside lib is Ionic-Angular. let me investigate further on this. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score -2):

Since each request is a new request in rest controller (due to its stateless behaviour), subsequent request will not be having the Cookie set by previous request. You may need to use singleton class having the Cookie object or Map<String, String> incase it will be same and while returing response to the client set cookies from the getter of singleton class

Comment: Don't, that will only lead to issues.